# Centred blocks in Css

Tags: html, css

I have a few blocks in list, and i need it without any margin, position center.
like this but without margin.

```css
ul{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px
} 
.colors{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
 .colors li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 8px;
    width: 38px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.product{
width: 450px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="product">  
  <div class="colors">                            
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don`t use Javascript. Just CSS. Now it`s on `display:inline-block`, but when inline block i have some margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `ul` as a flex container it will erase `white-space` .

You may add some vertical `margin` to `li` and `padding` to parent container if needed

```css
ul{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
    display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
} 
.colors{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
 .colors li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 8px;
    width: 38px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

.product{
width: 450px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="product">  
  <div class="colors">                            
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
      <li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers by default give a 3px space for text spacing but in your case you don't have text so you can just add

```
ul{
  font-size:0;
}
```

Comment: @GoogleParamoik cheers! :) please mark my answer and up-vote it if you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use any code for this, you just need to minify the HTML code and white-spaces will be automatically removed.

Like this:

```
<div class="product">  
  <div class="colors">                            
    <ul>
<li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#00ff00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#0f0f00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#f00f00;"></li>
<li style="background-color:#00f00f;"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```